# Can a document class be installed locally inside a file?

Tags: document-classes, class-options

I have 2 documents each in a different document class.

Can I somehow add one file to the other preserving the formatting?

Is there a way to locally install inside one of the documents the .cls and .sty files used by the other document and paste the tex file of the former into it?

Comment: If the layout of the document is similar, with enough hacking you can (more differences == more hacking). If they are too different, it might be easier to just compile one of them and include the generated pdf with `\includepdf` (from the `pdfpages` package). Without seeing an example of these documents its hard to say more

Comment: My only requirement is that the page numbering needs to continue. Will \includepdf do that?

Comment: what is stopping you just inputting the two documents (without their preamble and document environments) into a combined document?

Comment: Because each of them uses very localized commands coming from their stylefiles!

Comment: @gradstudent The page is inserted without modification. The page numbering of the document being compiled will still increase for each page output. You can compile the included document with a different numbering though. But again, impossible to actually help without seeing the documents

Comment: I tried the "\includepdf{filename.pdf}". It just added in the first page of the "filename" without even running the page numbers.

Comment: @gradstudent Yes, that includes only the first page. Try `\includepdf[pages=-]{filename.pdf}` to include all of them, or `\includepdf[pages=a-b]{filename.pdf}` to include from page `a` to `b`.

Comment: in my experience it's usually possible to include the two source files in to one: either the markup is similar so they naturally use the preamble or it is radically different so including definitions from both documents in the same preamble works without clashes. You only have an issue if there are clashing definitions and to convert initial pages like titles into sections or whatever but that needs to be done anyway to make a consistent combined document.